# Installing pip using pypy3 in an Ubuntu Docker image

Tags: software-installation, python, docker

After installing `pypy3` like so:

```bsh
apt-get -y install pypy3
```

The following error occurs when trying to [set up `pip`](https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/install.html#installing-more-modules):

```
# pypy3 -m ensurepip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pypy3/lib-python/3/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/pypy3/lib-python/3/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/pypy3/lib-python/3/ensurepip/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(ensurepip._main())
  File "/usr/lib/pypy3/lib-python/3/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 221, in _main
    version="pip {}".format(version()),
  File "/usr/lib/pypy3/lib-python/3/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 71, in version
    assert len(wheel_names) == 1, wheel_names
AssertionError: []
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | pypy3
```

Works for me. I have found using the get-pip.py file to be reliable